# Autodesk Forge - How to update(or modify) object create date for extend it

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have an app that upload a file to the Autodesk Forge server. (I use 2-legged bucket and oss api)

My app's bucket policy is 'temporary' and objects in bucket are delete after 30 days.

And I want to make function for extend deadline of object 
(like autodesk forge viewer sample's 'extend' button did)

Any suggestion to extend deadline of object?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately changing the retention policy of an existing bucket is not yet possible ...

We are aware though that this is a good to have feature and will definitely consider implementing going forward.

As of now you'd need (delete and then) create (another) bucket and upload the objects again ... (can't exactly copy objects between buckets either ...

Comment: Thank you Bryan. But I wonder that how sample viewer in autodesk forge homepage has the button which extend expire date of object... How can they do that ? Maybe can I edit object's create date or modified date? Is it possible?

Comment: That's obviously achieved using internal APIs - we might release them in the future but currently there's no immediate plan to do so unfortunately, plus those objects are actually the derivatives (the generated output from the conversion job) and hence adhere to another independent policy than the bucket objects...